# Electorate badge, my questions or someone else's?

Tags: discussion, questions, voting, electorate-badge

I'm confused as to what is mean by 600 votes and 25% or more of them being on questions...by "questions", do they mean questions that *I've* asked, or other user's questions?  or is it total?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interesting part is *"Voted on"* - you can't vote on your own questions. ;)

Ergo: You voted on 600 questions and of all your votes at least 25% were spent on questions.

Comment: see comment above.  You have accepted answer because you were first...

Comment: Actually, i was 2 seconds late ;)

Answer (score 3):

It means that you have voted at least 600 times and at least 25% of those votes that you cast were on questions rather than answers.  You can't vote on your own question, therefore it is for someone else's question.